# Complex If condition in typo3 fluid template inside the css class

Tags: php, typo3, fluid-layout, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-flow

I'm facing an issue in the following code

```
<div class="panel-icon {f:if(condition: '{0:panel.id}=={0:123}', then: 'icon-update', else: 'icon-{icon}')}"></div>
```

Currently the above code check if the `panel.id` equals to `123` then apply the `icon-update` to css class else whatever the icon being passed through `{icon}`

it works fine, but my requirement is I have 3 different `panel.id` and if any of those panel id's have passed, then the `icon-update` should be applied.

These are the approches I tried, but they're not working for me

Approach 1

```
<div class="panel-icon {f:if(condition: '{0:panel.id}=={0:123,0:456,0:789}', then: 'icon-update', else: 'icon-{icon}')}"></div>
```

Approach 2

```
<div class="panel-icon {f:if(condition: '{0:panel.id, 1:panel.id, 2:panel.id}=={0:123, 1:456, 2:789}', then: 'icon-update', else: 'icon-{icon}')}"></div>
```

I was tyring to find a clean solution for this, but still no luck. Any typo3 expert there to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by myself for my question and I'm posting it here if anyone looking for a solution like me

```
<v:if stack="{0:panel.id, 1:'==', 2:'123', 3:'||', 4:panel.id, 5: '==', 6:'456', 7:'||', 8:panel.id, 9:'==', 10:'789'}">
   <f:then><div class="icon icon-update"></div></f:then>
   <f:else><div class="icon icon-{icon}"></div></f:else>
</v:if>
```

This solved my problem